# How to replace a double backslash with a single backslash in a unicoded string

Tags: java

My code snippet:

```
String s1 = "\\u4f60\\u597d";  
System.out.println(s1); //print：\u4f60\u597d  
String s2 = "\u4f60\u597d";  
System.out.println(s2); //print chinese character：你好
```

I want to change s1 to s2, that is to say replace a double backslash with a single backslash or some others method to fulfill this action. I have tried below approach but it failed because compiler prompted *invalid unicode*:

```
"\\u4f60\\u597d".replace("\\\\u", "\u");
```

Comment: Replacing in Java won't work. You need to replace it in your source code, and the compiler turns it into 你好.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to give a look at [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache Commons.

```
    String s1 = "\\u4f60\\u597d";
    System.out.println(s1); //print：\u4f60\u597d        
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s1));
    String s2 = "\u4f60\u597d";
    System.out.println(s2); //print chinese character
```

Yields:

> \u4f60\u597d
>
> 你好
>
> 你好

Comment: thanks all very much, the problem is solved using "StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()"

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, then please mark the green 'very good' :)

Answer (score 0):

download the commons-lang.jar library in http://commons.apache.org/lang/

StringEscapeUtils class may be useful for that.

Comment: thank you very much, the problem is solved using "StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()"

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me

```
String s1 = "\\u4f60\\u597d";  
String ans = s1.replace("\\\\", "\\");
```